# 2nd order non-linear DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this seemingly simple problem but I just have no idea where to start. So the question is:
Consider a system which satisfies $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx + \alpha  x^3$$
where $\alpha > 0$.
 (a) Show that the force does not always restore the  mass towards $x=0$.

(b) Which positions are equilibrium positions? Are they stable?

How exactly should I go about this problem? Should I integrate twice to get the $x(t)$ equation or is that the wrong approach?

Comment: I think you first of all want to define mathematically what (a) and (b) mean in terms of functions of $x$ and the constants. You may not need to solve to get $x$ as a function of $t$. But if you do want to solve for $x(t)$, yes, it looks like integrating twice is a good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with 
$$
m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx + \alpha  x^3
$$

(a)for small x: $kx > \alpha x^{3}$ then force is retarding when $kx < \alpha x^{3}$ the force accelerates. So in the latter case the mass does not always return to zero.

(b)
Taking the rhs of the above equation as $V(x)$ we find the equilibrium points as the roots of $V(x)$ which occur at
$$
x_{0} = 0\\
x_{0} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{k}{\alpha}}
$$

to find the nature of the stability points we can perturb the solution about $x_{0}$ as $x=x_{0} + \delta x$. inserting into the original equation and linearise worth respect to $\delta x$ we find
$$
\frac{d^{2}\delta x}{dt^{2}} = \frac{dV\left(\delta x\right)}{dx} = \left(-k + 3\alpha x_{0}^{2}\right)\delta x
$$
Then you would solve for $\delta x$ and then plug the fixed points into the resulting equation for $\delta x$ and depending on the nature of $\delta x$'s will determine if the points are stable,unstable etc etc.

$\textbf{Appendix}$

we can use the identity 
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = p\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{p^{2}}{2}\right)
$$
where $p=\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Subbing into the original equation we have
$$
m\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{p^{2}}{2}\right) = -kx + \alpha  x^3
$$
this yields
$$
\frac{p^{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{m}\left(-k\frac{x^{2}}{2} + \alpha\frac{x^{4}}{4} + C\right)
$$

Now in physics we can either keep C or choose it to be zero. If we focus on C = 0 case

$$
p = x\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2m}\left( x^{2} -\frac{2k}{\alpha}\right)} = \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
this leads to 
$$
\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{\left( x^{2} -\frac{2k}{\alpha}\right)}}dx = \int \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2m}}dt
$$
transforming again with $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{\alpha}}}$
the lhs becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{\alpha}}}\int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^{2}-1}}du = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2m}}t + C_{1}
$$
making a final substitution of $u = sec(x)$ we can solve the lys integral to become
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{\alpha}}}u = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2m}}t + C_{1}
$$

with the final solution of

$$
x(t) = \mathrm{sec}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t +  C_{1}\right)
$$

Comment: That looks great but do we need $x(t)$? We are asked about force and mass: I'm not sure either of these involve $x(t)$.

Comment: @TooTone I just realised after completing! Do you think i should remove the answer since it does not satisfy the OP question?

Comment: well you've done a lot of work there that the OP might find useful (plenty of times I've done the same). Why not try to address the OP's questions and leave what you've done as an appendix?

Comment: @Chinny84 what exactly is p?

Comment: @TooTone I will modify the answer. Cheers for the advice..I just saw equation and went full steam ahead.

Comment: Richard (with thanks to @TooTone) the answer should be complete including the definition of p. TooTone, that is some bad times! The nearest I felt to that "disappointment" was when I wrote up a full solution, left it a few days, and the OP had wrote up a duplicate question and then accepted an answer from someone else!! But I still accept your prediciment was far worse..ha.

Comment: Nice answer, Chinny84. I think someone should edit the question until your answer is *the* answer! I noticed that as I was reading, I didn't care what the original question was any more.

Comment: yep, good job! :)

Comment: @TooTone Cheers. Lets see if it holds up.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you. As you might tell from the commentary, it was initially a mistake to do the solution. But what the hell its out there, and open for improvements upon such as the C!=0 case.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks for your help!! I really appreciate, I had no idea where to start really. One quick question for (a), is there a way to *show* what you said mathematically or is it just written?

Comment: @Richard No problems! As for (a) you can discuss mathematically by simply putting inequalities as I did above, or use definition of $V(x)$ and plot it and you can graph where the system will return to 0 and will not. I will have a think and return tomorrow if no real mathematicians (I am a theoretical physicist) have fleshed answer (a) out for you.